# no redirect occurs when the client received a 302 response from the server

Tags: node.js, redirect, next.js, middleware

With each request, the server checks if the user has a subscription, if not, then sends such a request:

```
res.writeHead(302, {Location: '/profile'}); // not work with code 301 307 308

res.end();

return;
```

or

```
res.redirect("/profile",302);
```

After the client has received the page from the server, there is no redirect. Might be a problem with the `SSR`.

i tried also using the `middleware` from `next js` but it has few features so it doesn't fit.

Comment: How are you making the request from the client? Normally, the client would need to handle such responses (assuming you're using `fetch`/`axios` on the client-side).

Comment: @juliomalves The client processes and the server renders a new page and sends it to the client, but the client does not render and redirect after receiving the page. I think this is the problem with ssr or middleware from nextAuth

Comment: Can you please show us the client-side code?

Comment: @juliomalves this is the answer to all requests to the server, on the server I check if the client has a subscription, if not, then I redirect him to another page. Therefore, it doesn't matter what request I wrote in axios. Maybe you have other ideas to check the subscription of the client? now I have a helper function where I can write conditions, it works as a middleware. built-in middleware from next many restrictions.

Comment: If you're using fetch/axios to make the request to the server you need to handle the redirect on the client yourself. It won't redirect just because you're returning a 302. Hence why I'm asking for you to show the client-side code.

Comment: @juliomalves I did not do any processing on the client side. I just need to redirect any fetch requests from different pages after checking the subscription on the server. Could you advise on the best way to do this?

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. How is the client making the requests to the server exactly? Where is the server code you provided located? If you could provide a [mre] that'd be very helpful.